# Soul residing in one's mind

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul

I heard from someone that the *soul* resides in one's mind/ brain.

Does anyone where the source for this can be found?

Comment: Look at toras chaim chumash from mossad rav kook on bereishis where G-d infused the soul in Adam. I remember one of the rishonim says it there

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6131/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27008/759

Comment: @DoubleAA looks like a dupe, yeah, IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the brain the seat of the soul?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/is-the-brain-the-seat-of-the-soul)

Comment: Rabbi Yehoshua and Rabbi Eli'ezer dispute where wisdom is (in heart or brain) in the [beginning of Midrash Mishley](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Mishlei.1.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nefesh HaChaim 1:14:

> מחשבה היא בחינת הנשמה שהיא המלמדת לאדם דיעה ובינה בתוה"ק. לכן עיקר משכנה הוא במוח כלי המחשבה
>
> Thought is the faculty of the soul (Neshama) which teaches the person knowledge and understanding in Torah.  Therefore its primary residence is in the mind, the tool of thought.

Comment: People also say this in the prayer before putting on _t'filin_: "_shehan'shama sheb'mochi_".